# How to inject with Guice `Module` where constructor accepts Class?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

The title describes my problem.

E.g.

```
public class EntryDAOModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(EntryDAO.class).to(EntryDTOMongoImpl.class); // what should this be?       
    }
}
```

As shown, what should be the parameter to `.to`, given the below:

```
public class GenericDAOMongoImpl<T, K extends Serializable> extends BasicDAO<T, K> {
    public GenericDAOMongoImpl(Class<T> entityClass) throws UnknownHostException {
        super(entityClass, ConnectionManager.getDataStore());
    }
}

public class EntryDAOMongoImpl extends GenericDAOMongoImpl<EntryDTOMongoImpl, ObjectId> implements EntryDAO<EntryDTOMongoImpl> {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EntryDAOMongoImpl.class);

    @Inject
    public EntryDAOMongoImpl(Class<EntryDTOMongoImpl> entityClass) throws UnknownHostException {
        super(entityClass);
    }
    ...
}
```

How can I instantiate the `EntryDAOMongoImpl` class like so:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new EntryDAOModule());
this.entryDAO = injector.getInstance(EntryDAO.class); // what should this be?
```

Comment: are you trying to supply EntryDTOMongoImpl.class from the Constructor of EntryDAOMongImpl to the super() Constructor of GenericDAOMongoImpl?

Comment: @johncarl - yes sorry - added the `GenericDAOMongoImpl` class for clarification.

Comment: ah, I see... answer on its way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are going to need here is to create a factory.  Using assisted injection can help you here.

You can see my [previous post regarding assisted injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154410/guice-injecting-only-some-of-the-constructor/9154502#9154502)

but here's the exact solution for your case:

EntryDAOMongoImpl:

```
public class EntryDAOMongoImpl extends GenericDAOMongoImpl<EntryDTOMongoImpl, ObjectId> implements EntryDAO<EntryDTOMongoImpl> {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EntryDAOMongoImpl.class);

    @Inject
    public EntryDAOMongoImpl(@Assisted Class<EntryDTOMongoImpl> entityClass) throws UnknownHostException {
        super(entityClass);
    }
    ...
}
```

Factory:

```
public interface EntryDAOFactory {
    public EntryDAOMongoImpl buildEntryDAO(Class<EntryDTOMongoImpl> entityClass);
}
```

Module:

```
public class EntryDAOModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        //bind(EntryDAO.class).to(EntryDAOMongoImpl.class); // what should this be?

        FactoryModuleBuilder factoryModuleBuilder = new FactoryModuleBuilder();
        install(factoryModuleBuilder.build(EntryDAOFactory.class));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new EntryDAOModule());
EntryDAOFactory factory = injector.getInstance(EntryDAOFactory.class);
this.entryDAO = factory.buildEntryDAO(entityClass);
```

If you are going to be using the EntryDAOMongoImpl as a singelton (natural usage of a singleton imo) then you can do the following without assisted injection within your module:

```
public class EntryDAOModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        EtnryDTOMongoImpl dto = new EntryDTOMongoImpl(TargetEntry.class); //guessing here
        bind(EntryDAO.class).toInstance(new EntryDAOMongoImpl(dto)); // singleton   
    }
}
```

Let me know if that helps

Comment: this worked; I'm going to have to read more into DI and Guice - it seems like this defeats the purpose? I now need to create a factory for all DTO's that follow the above idiom. Also, now I have to make changes in two locations if I want to use a different DTO implementation; `EntryDAOFactory` and in the usage class.

Comment: Doesn't defeat the purpose at all.  You may include non-@Assisted injected dependencies in the same constructor.  This technique alleviates a ton of Factory boilerplate.

Comment: considering your question, Ive added an alternative.