# Is it possible to combine assisted and mapped injection with Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Basically these two approaches into one:

[Can Guice automatically create instances of different classes based on a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669413/can-guice-automatically-create-instances-of-different-classes-based-on-a-paramet)

[Guice injecting only some of the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154410/guice-injecting-only-some-of-the-constructor)

For example:
User operation handlers are created with mapped and assisted injections, i.e. each needs some static bindings as well as an operation context that is created dynamically from a request.

```
class OpHandler { void handle()... }
class SendHandler extends OpHandler {
    public SendHandler(DAL dal, SendContext context) { ... }
}
class ReceiveHandler extends OpHandler {
    public ReceiveHandler(DAL dal, ReceiveContext context) { ... }
}

servlet:
onGet() {
    op = resolveOp();
    switch (op) {
    SEND: create SendContext and pass it somehow to ioc.getInstance(SendHandler.class)
    RECEIVE: create ReceiveContext and pass it somehow to ioc.getInstance(ReceiveHandler.class)
    }
}
```